# IOS By clicking on a UITableViewCell scroll to another UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a UITableView with 10 rows. By clicking on the first row I want to scroll to row 5 of the UITableView.

How can i do that?

Comment: What part do you need help with? Handling a row being selected or scrolling to a specific row? Have you looked at any of the `UITableView` related documentation for either of these?

Comment: scrolling to a specific row

Comment: Look at the docs for `UITableView`. You will find what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        [tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:5 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Should work!

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath
 {
     if(indexPath.row == 0)    {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:4 inSection:0];
       [tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
     }
}
```